# Cannot access Github Action MSSQL database in tests

Tags: java, sql-server, github-actions

I have a Spring Boot application with MSSQL database. I would like to run github action and run tests for pull requests and merges to master. However I have problem with connecting to database from GA tests. My application uses YAML configuration and I have separate config file for CI tests.
Here is workflow:

```
name: Java CI with Maven

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services: 
      mssql:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        env:
          SA_PASSWORD: myPassword
          ACCEPT_EULA: 'Y'
          DBNAME: test
        ports:
        - 1433:1433
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -ntp -U clean test -P junit-ci
```

And junit-ci config file:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://mssql:1433;database=test;
    username: sa
    password: myPassword
```

And here is error:

```
[main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host mssql, port 1433 has failed. Error: "mssql. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:285)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2434)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) instead. This way it is the testcontainers Java library which takes care of starting a database to use it for Integration Testing. It is sooo much easier than the path you are currently on. IMHO.

Your GitHub Action YAML then becomes simpler.  It will just be pure Maven actions. You also make your test code less dependent on GitHub Actions as your CI system.

Using Testcontainers has other advantages: Your test can have full control over the database (or the container in which it runs). For example you can have a test where you kill the container during the test, thereby similating the effect on your application on a database which suddenly is lost.

Btw: Strictly speaking, what you are attempting is not *Unit Tests*, but *Integration Tests*. Maven makes a distinction. It is advisable to make this distinction. Integration Tests are often quite heavy. By using Testcontainers approach the database container will only be started when you tell Maven to execute Integration Tests. In your example, the database container is always started, regardless if it is needed.